# Aggregate after exception from ftp consumer: FatalFallbackErrorHandler

Tags: apache-camel, sftp

My camel route tries to pick up some files from sftp, transfer them to network, and delete them from sftp. If the sftp is unreachable after 3 attempts, I want the route to send an email warning the admin about the problem.

For this reason my sftp address has the following parameters:

```
maximumReconnectAttempts=2&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true
```

In case the network location is not available, i want the route to notify the admin and **not** delete the files from sftp. 
For this reason i have set *.handled(false)* in onException.

However, when connecting to sftp fails, aggregation also fails and no emails are coming. I have made a minimalist example below:

```
/configure
  onException(Throwable.class)
    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
    .redeliveryDelay(1000)
    .handled(false)
    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, LOG, "XXX - Error moving files")
    .to(AGGREGATEROUTE)
    .end();

  from(downloadFrom)
  .to(to)
  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, "XXX - Moving file OK")
  .to(AGGREGATEROUTE);

  from(AGGREGATEROUTE)
  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, "XXX - Starting aggregation.")
  .aggregate(constant(true), new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
      .completionFromBatchConsumer()
      .completionTimeout(10000)
  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, "XXX - Aggregation completed, sending mail.");
```

In the logs i see:

```
16:02| ERROR | CamelLogger.java 156 | XXX - Error moving files
```

Then the logs for the Exception occurring during connection.

And then this:

```
16:02| ERROR | FatalFallbackErrorHandler.java 174 | Exception occurred while trying to handle previously thrown exception on exchangeId: ID-LP0641-1552662095664-0-2 using: [Pipeline[[Channel[Log(proefjes.camel_cursus.routebuilders.MoveWithPickupExceptions)[XXX - Error moving files]], Channel[sendTo(direct://aggregate)]]]].
16:02| ERROR | FatalFallbackErrorHandler.java 172 | \--> New exception on exchangeId: ID-LP0641-1552662095664-0-2
   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://user@mycompany.nl:22
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:149)
```

I do not see "XXX - Starting aggregation." which i would expect to see in the log. Does some kind of error occur befor aggregation? The breakpoint on aggregate(*, *) is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

First, I just want to clarify something. You write "In case the network location is not available, i want the route to notify the admin and not delete the files from sftp", but shouldn't that be obvious anyhow? I mean, if the network location is not available, wouldn't deleting the files from sftp be impossible?

It's a little confusing that your exception handler is also routing `.to(AGGREGATEROUTE)`. Given that you want to email an admin, shouldn't that be in the exception handler, not in the happy path? Why would you and how would you "aggregate" a connection failure?

Finally, and here I think is a real problem with your implementation, you may have misunderstood what `handled(false)` does. Setting this to false means routing should stop and propagate the exception returned to the caller. I'm not sure what having to the `.to(AGGREGATEROUTE)` would do in this case, but I'm not surprised it's not being called.

I suggest trying a few things. I don't have your code so I'm not sure which will work best. These are all related and any might work:

- Change `handled(false)` to `handled(true)`.
- Replace `handled` with `continued(true)`.
- Use a Dead Letter Channel.

Reference:

- [Handle and Continue Exceptions](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/exception-clause.adoc#marking-exceptions-as-handled)
- [Dead Letter Channel](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/dead-letter-channel.adoc)

Comment: Either end could be unavailable, if the to-endpoint is unavailable i want rollback, so i have handled(false) and i prefer aggregation so i dont get an email for every file that could not be delivered. In any case i do not want to swallow the exception, which is what handled(true) does, in my understanding. I could continue but then how do i make sure no files are deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Since errorhandling is different depending on which endpoint causes the error, i have solved this by having two different versions of onException:

```
     //configure exception on sft end
    onException(Throwable.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(2)
    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
    .redeliveryDelay(1000)
    .onWhen(new hasSFTPErrorPredicate())
     // .continued(true) //  tries to connect once, mails and continues to aggregation with empty exchange
    //.handled(false) // tries to connect twice but does not reach mail
      .handled(true)  // tries to connect once, does reach mail
    // handled not defined: tries to connect twice but does not reach mail
      .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, "XXX - SFTP exception")
      .to(MAIL_ROUTE)
      .end();

   // exception anywhere else
    onException(Throwable.class)
     .maximumRedeliveries(2)
     .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN)
     .redeliveryDelay(1000)
     .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, LOG, "XXX - Error moving file ${file:name}: ${exception}")
     .to(AGGREGATEROUTE)
     .handled(false)
     .end();
```

Exceptions occuring at the sftp end are handled in the first onException, because there the hasSFTPErrorPredicate returns 'true'. All this predicate does is check if any exception or their cause has "Cannot connect to sftp:" in the message.
No rollback is required in this case because nothing has happened yet.

Any other exception is handled by the second onException.